# Definite integral of the following question

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate:
> $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{4x\ln (x)}{x^4+4x^2+1}dx$$

I took $x^2$ common from the denominator and then substituted $\ln (x) =u$, and then I was stuck. The result turns out to be
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{4u}{(e^u+e^{-u})^2+2}dx$$

Comment: write out your attempt please

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and try editing your post. Without any improvement, others may not be interested in answering, and the question may get closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This integral cannot be calculated with "conventional" methods. The trick I will tell you, is to sub $x=1/t$ and then $dx=-1/t^2dt$. I leave it op to you to do the algebra. You will end up with the negative form of the given integral. In other words, if the given integral is $I$, you end up with $I=-I$ and so $I=0$. This is just the overview of the method. You need to work out the rudiments. That's your exercise otherwise you haven't learned anything from it

Comment: how did you figure out,that we need to use the above substitution?Like is it applicable on some format of questions or is it just a clicking base substitution?

Comment: The truth is, I have seen problems like this one before. The thing is, you are integrating from zero to infinity, $ln(-x)=-lnx$ and the headcoefficient and constant in the polynomial are the same, being $1$. In short, that is why it works.

Comment: thank you!Can you send some more questions of these types with a link or pdf please.Much appriciated

Comment: These problems do not appear that frequent. They are not "staple" problems. Usually you will find them in the section "improper integrals" in the integration chapter. Any type of $lnx$ in the numerator with a quadratic denominator (with a negative discriminant, why?) where the head coefficient and constant is the same, will work. Integrating from 0 to infinity. Now you can try this out yourself

Answer (score 1):

Let's write $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x \ln(x)}{x^4+4x^2+1}dx=\int_0^1\frac{x \ln(x)}{x^4+4x^2+1}dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{x \ln(x)}{x^4+4x^2+1}dx$$

For the first integral we change the variable $x\to z=1/x$ and by a simple calculation we show that it is equal to the second integral with a different sign.
This approach makes it straightforward that for any $s>1$ we have $$\int_{\frac{1}{s}}^s \frac{x \ln(x)}{x^4+4x^2+1}dx=0$$ Original question concerned the case $s \to \infty$.

The change of variable is obvious for those working with elliptic integrals.